# Has Superboy-Prime ever been featured in any media besides comics?

Tags: dc, superboy-prime

I've been reading up on him for a quite a while now and it surprised me that I haven't seen a character that powerful and evil in any animated or regular show. Does anybody know anything he was in that I might be missing?

Comment: For the record, comics are media.  So the trivial answer is 'Yes.'

Comment: @Jeff Are we all happy?

Comment: @Valorum should we have tags for the other Superboys too? A couple questions were misusing that tag.

Comment: @amaranth - In this instance, the tag seems to have been used correctly since the question specifically refers to Superboy-Prime. I've edited the tag wiki to make it a little clearer how the tag should be used.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for the tag wiki. If you think that the other Superboys should have a tag, feel free to make one. There have been a couple Superboy-non-prime (?) questions lately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Superboy-Prime has never been portrayed in any licensed media apart from the comics.

Comment: Although he was never portrayed, he was referenced in an episode of _Young Justice_ by [Match](http://youngjustice.wikia.com/wiki/Match) by using _"his heat vision to burn an S-shield in his chest_".

Comment: The backwards "S"'s resemblance to a "2" could also be seen as a reference to Bizarro, with his "#1" or "Bizarro #1" signs.

Comment: That's a good point :)